# TFS 2010 and .htaccess file in source control

Tags: team-foundation-server

We use Team foundation server 2010 for our web projects, and sometimes we use PHP and .htaccess files. Is there a way to upload any file which name starts with dot (.htaccess, .test etc.) to TFS? Any server configuration changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not limitation of Team Foundation Server. If you Map TFS folder to "local" (network path) folder , then this error may occur.

TFS normally and by default support .htacces files.

Comment: How is this not a limitation? Unless you wish to categorise it as a bug instead?

Comment: It is limitation of Windows and NTFS/File shareing for storing files wich starts with dot, it does not have nothing with TFS